# Giving goal points without using rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In various scenarios we need to give goals to the robot and using rviz is the most popular way to do it in the ROS community. However, in various low level processors (viz. Raspberry Pi and other ARM processors) or in a bare bones installation one may not have the luxury of getting OGRE working, hence no rviz. So, what options do we have then, is it possible to give goal points using some other means ?

Typically a command line execution as

*[rospackage] [executable] [goal-x, goal-y]*

may be very useful, does such exist ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56868/giving-goal-points-without-using-rviz/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2013-03-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From you command, I assume you mean without a GUI?

In that case, just do what rviz does: It sends a message to a topic (usually /move_base_simple/goal). You can do the same via `rostopic pub`.

A wrapper script that expects x,y,theta could be easily done.

From software, you should use the actionlib interface.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-03-03**:
@dornhege I see what you are getting at !! seems possible, do you guess the command structure I have suggested can indeed be implemented ? [rospackage] [executable] [goal-x, goal-y] ??

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-03**:
Sure. Just write a wrapper script that takes x,y and calls `rostopic pub` with the correct parameters fed in. If you put that script in a ROS package, you'll have exactly the syntax you wanted.